# COUNT number of variables in array that are not NULL 

Tags: php

I have an array range `$row['ADDwav'] - $row['ADDwav16']`

How can I count the number of these that isset() and not NULL?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) with [`is_null`](http://php.net/is_null) (as callback) for that:

```
count(array_filter($row, "is_null"))
```

If you want the ones that are *not* null, then you'd have to subtract that from the original array length still `count($row) - count(array_filter(...))`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($row as $r)
{
    if($r !== null)
    {
        $counter++;
    }
}

echo "Total not null items : " . $counter;
```

The above code will work. Also the values into foreach are all set, otherwhise will not loop through them ;)

In case your array is like that :

```
$row = array(
    'ADDwav' => null,
    'ADDwav1' => 'somevalue',
    'ADDwav2' => 'anothervalue',
    'ADDwav3' => '',
    'ADDwav...' => '...',
    'ADDwav16' => null
);
```

and you like to count the values that are not empty or null then you have to modify the code in the next form :

```
$counter = 0;

foreach($row as $k => $r)
{
    if($r !== null || $r !== '')
    {
        $counter++;
    }
}

echo "Total not null items : " . $counter;
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_filter and is_null

```
   foreach($row as $r)

      if($r !== null)
...
..
.
```

Answer (score 0):

This one will remove the array which is false or null...

```
            $entry = array(
               0 => 'foo',
               1 => false,
               2 => -1,
               3 => null,
               4 => ''
              );

            echo  count(array_filter($entry));
```

Comment: `array_filter` w\out a callback will eliminate all that are equal to `false`, which is not the same as "not null".